# How to do you create a function that accepts an input and assigns it to a variable?

Tags: c++, function, input

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string userInput, userName;
```

The function below takes an input from the user

```
string takeInput() 
    {
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin,userInput);
    }
```

the takeInput() function would be called and its variable should be stored in the userName variable but nothing shows up when I run the program call the userName in the last cout.

```
int main() {
    cout<<"Name:    ";
    userName = takeInput();
    
    cout<<"My name is "<<userName;
}
```

Comment: You don't return anything from your function

Comment: Please stop doing `using namespace std`

Comment: you are using global variables and at the same time declare your funciton to return the string, but you dont return it. Frankly this looks like you skipped the section on returning a value from a function in your learning material

Comment: Remove the global variables, instead use local variable `std::string userInput; getline(...); return userInput;` , and then in the main use another local variable: `string userInput = takeInput();`. That should do what you want. Next step is to understand what was changed.

Comment: The code should look like this `string takeInput() { string input; cin.ignore(); getline(cin, input); return input; }`. For some reason `return` is something that beginners don't learn, but how else would you return something from a function? As you found out it doesn't happen by magic.

Comment: Enable all warnings and use `-Werror`. [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings)